# Can i use all of c++ functionality using VISUAL c++?

Tags: .net, c++, api, visual-c++

Im having trouble finding a way to obtain wifi info such as RSSI and SSID using c# .net.

C++ Has access to the Native WIFI api.

If I opt to use VISUAL C++ instead of another compiler do i only have access to the .net classes or do i have access to the full c++ spectrum.

Many Thanks

Comment: This question doesn't make sense.  Do you mean "Can I use all of **.NET** functionality using Visual C++?"

Comment: Ok, ill edit. But my question is if I opt to use visual c++ does that mean i only have access to the .net classes or can i still use the whole c++ spectrum.

Comment: Ok, but your example of "native wifi" is not part of the "C++ spectrum"; it's a platform-specific feature.

Comment: Ok, if it's about semantics you go ahead and downvote. In this context, seeing as how it's not accesable directly through the .net languages but it is through c++ (and others) the wording of the question serves my purpose.

Comment: I didn't downvote.  Please don't get prissy when someone suggests that you should clarify your question.  Right now, it doesn't make sense.  Wi-Fi is not a standard C++ feature.  So it's not clear how your example fits in with what you're asking.

Comment: Then i apologise for accusing you. I think i should have simply asked if opting to use managed c++ instead of unmanaged c++ results in losing some of the c++ functionality. Like in j# you have access to java grammer but not the java classes. I thought it might have been something similar for VISUAL c++. That's why I asked. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lifting from the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_C++):

> Microsoft Visual C++ (often abbreviated as MSVC or VC++) is a
>   commercial, integrated development environment (IDE) product from
>   Microsoft for the C, C++, and C++/CLI programming languages

So in short, yes, Visual C++ is simply an IDE which allows you to work with the C++ programming language and you will have access to the whole C++ language (but will still need to rely upon libraries on the machines where you run your code).

There are certain Visual C++ project types which give you .Net extensions as well but if you want a pure C++ application then you can pick one of the projects such as `Win32 Console Application` which only give you the main C++ language.

For you requirement however, you might be able to stay with C# and instead look into [P/Invoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288468%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) which allows managed .Net code to call unmanaged code (including probably the libraries you want for retrieving things like SSIDs using the WIFI api you mention)

Comment: Thankyou. Ive spent a hell of a load of time researching this problem in c#, i just wanted a simple straight answer for a change. +1

Comment: I've tried looking at p/invoke. (even managed wifi api) i think it will be a bit more robust to go direct with c++. But thanks.

Answer (score 1):

With visual c++ you can totally access C# functionality (they are .NET libraries, so can communicate with everything that works on .NET).

Obviusly, you have also all the "basic" C++ functionality, is something like a fusion of 2 languages

Care by the way, you will have a **lot** of keywords with c++ due to the possibility to work with managed code and unmanaged.

Comment: Thanks for the warning. The c++ part of my program will only be to read ssid's and rssi's for AP'S. Im hoping to be able to take those values and be able to program the rest of my application in c#, as that is what im most comfortable with.